# 'and' 'or' operator in if statement

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe df as follow:

```
Name   Race(m)    Date  
Peter   2000    23/09/16  
Mary    100     23/09/16
Mary    400     23/09/16
Mary    200     23/09/16
Mary    400     24/09/17
John    800     23/09/16
```

I wanna add a column [X] to indicate how many races still have to go by that person on the same day such that:

```
Name   Race(m)    Date       X
Peter   2000    23/09/16     1
Peter   100     23/09/16     0
Mary    400     23/09/16     1
Mary    200     23/09/16     0
Mary    400     24/09/17     0
John    800     23/09/16     0
```

To make it happen:

```
content = df.values.tolist()
name = []
date = []
for each in content:
    if (each[0] not in name and (each[2] not in date)) or ((each[0] in name) and (each[2] not in date)) or ((each[0] not in name) and (each[2] in date)):
        remaining_race = 0
        for every in content:
            if every[0] == each[0] and every[2] == each[2]:
                remaining_race += 1
        remaining_race -= 1    
        name.append(each[0])
        date.append(each[2])
        each.append(remaining_race)

    else:
        remaining_race -= 1
        each.append(remaining_race)
```

However, the output is:

```
    Name   Race(m)    Date       X
    Peter   2000    23/09/16     1
    Peter   100     23/09/16     0
    Mary    400     23/09/16     -1
    Mary    200     23/09/16     -2
    Mary    400     24/09/17     0
    John    800     23/09/16     -3
```

How could I fix it?

Comment: I am no pandas expert, but I suspect that you do not need to write a for loop to do this efficiently and correctly in pandas.

Comment: then what should I do?

Comment: Your if-statement can be simplified to `if not (each[0] in name and each[2] in date)`

Comment: it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data=[["peter"],["peter"]], columns=["name"]) 
# count number of times each name occurs, put it in a dictionary
names = dict(df["name"].value_counts())

def num_races_left(name):
  names[name]-=1
  return names[name]

# for every name, look it up in the dict and reduce number by 1
df["X"] = df["name"].apply(num_races_left)
```

This returns the following

```
    name  X
0  peter  1
1  peter  0
```